# mySQL - how to code SELECT statement correctly

Tags: mysql

I have a mySQL `SELECT` statement with a combination of full text search and normal search in the `WHERE` condition and an additional `JOIN` like this

```
SELECT 
 customer.*, 
 countries.name as country
 FROM customer  
 LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.ID = customer.country_id 
 WHERE customer.num   = :keyword 
    OR customer.city  = :keyword  
    OR customer.email = :keyword 
    OR MATCH (customer.company) AGAINST (:keyword)
    OR countries.name = :keyword
```

Queries with a full text search into `(customer.company)` column returns `no result` as long as the table.column `countries.name` is part of the `WHERE` condition. But queries into `countries.name` itself are successful.

How to code the SELECT statement correctly to return a successful query using a combination of all WHERE components from above example ?

EDIT :

In a previous version I used this statment

```
 SELECT 
  customer.* ,
  countries.name
  FROM customer, countries 
  WHERE customer.country_id=countries.ID 
  AND MATCH (customer.company) AGAINST (:keyword)

  UNION

  SELECT 
  customer.*, 
  countries.name
  FROM customer, countries 
  WHERE customer.country_id=countries.ID 
  AND countries.name=:keyword
```

which works well. I just do not know if this is the efficient way to query two tables with different searchs (full text and normal). Also when I search in more than 2 columns the code is getting blown up easily, which I would like to avoid.

Any more ideas and help is welcome

Comment: I don't understand your goal can you put a sample data and it's expected result

Answer (score 0):

You should check for `NULLs` since you are using a `LEFT JOIN` :

```
SELECT 
     customer.*, 
     countries.name as country
 FROM customer  
 LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.ID = customer.country_id 
 WHERE customer.num   = :keyword 
    OR customer.city  = :keyword  
    OR customer.email = :keyword 
    OR MATCH (customer.company) AGAINST (:keyword)
    OR (countries.name = :keyword OR countries.name IS NULL)
```

Just for clarification, conditions on the right table of a `LEFT JOIN` should be placed only inside the `ON` clause, not the `WHERE` clause . This is a bit different, since you want to compare it against all the other conditions, therefore - the `NULL` comparison.

Comment: Updated condition with `IS Null` - same problem

Comment: CONTINUE from above comment : As I wrote in my question above, a query into the `countries.name` (2nd table) has success but not into `customer.company` (full text column). Only  when I remove the WHERE clause `countries.name` then I get results.

Comment: How to place a `WHERE` clause in an `ON` clause of the `LEFT JOIN` statement ?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is just set a default value = `''` to `countries.name` if it's null using `CASE WHEN`

```
(CASE WHEN countries.name is null then 'default value' else countries.name END)
```

new query

```
SELECT 
 customer.*, 
 countries.name as country
 FROM customer  
 LEFT JOIN countries ON countries.ID = customer.country_id 
 WHERE customer.num   = :keyword 
    OR customer.city  = :keyword  
    OR customer.email = :keyword 
    OR MATCH (customer.company) AGAINST (:keyword)
    OR (CASE WHEN countries.name is null then '' else countries.name END) = :keyword
```

Comment: sorry , I dont understand your proposal. Can you please post a complete SELECT sample ?

Comment: `OR (:keyword == '' AND countries.name is null)` produces a pphp `parse error`

Comment: can I see your php maybe it's an escape string error

Comment: @Ben I have another solution.

Comment: sorry doesn't work. I do not get any results neither on `customer.company` (full text) nor on `countries.name` (which I also want to query)